# Javascript: Loop, iterate, and add new values

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Goal: Gather all the results from a loop (that loops through JSON object array) and add those values together to produce the overall number of credits for a user. Every time they take a course, they receive credit, but right now, I need to figure out how to add them together. I am new to Javascript and am trying to figure out how to create a function that continually updates (via a for loop), so that I can produce it via HTML in the web page.

I was looking at this [stack example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472853/looping-and-adding-together-the-values-generated) that loops together values (for a game) and tried to mimic it. I was also looking at the for loop example via this [JS tutorial](http://www.dofactory.com/tutorial/javascript-loops).

```
var sum = 0; for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {    sum = sum + i; }
alert("Sum = " + sum);    // => Sum = 1275
```

> It consists of three parts, separated by semicolons. The first is the
>   initializer (var i = 1) which initializes the loop and is executed
>   only once at the start. The second is a test condition (i <= 50). When
>   a conditional expression evaluates to true, the body of the loop is
>   executed. When false, the loop terminates. The third part is an
>   updater (i++) which is invoked after each iteration. The updater
>   typically increments or decrements the loop counter.

My Code:

```
    //Function that returns HTML for successfully retrieved results
    function resultsHTML(JSONResponseObjectArray) {
        var ddObjectArray = JSONResponseObjectArray;
        var resultString = '';
        //Loop through JSON Object Array
        for(eeIndex in ddObjectArray) {
            var creditHours = ddObjectArray[eeIndex].creditHours;

        resultString += ceHTML(creditHours);
        console.log("credit hours: " + creditHours);

}
```

}

```
    function addCredits(){
      var result = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i <= 0; i++){
        result = creditHours + i;
        }
        return result;
          console.log('new results ' + result);
      }
```

Output of Array (via console):

```
credit hours: null
list.js:114 credit hours: 4
list.js:114 credit hours: 6
list.js:114 credit hours: null
list.js:114 credit hours: 4
list.js:114 credit hours: null
```

Comment: do you have any example array with JSON objects?

Comment: Couple small issues. First off, your `addCredits` function is inside of your other function. Second, `resultsHTML` isn't closed. Third, your `console.log` won't happen because it's after a `return` which ends the function.

Answer (score 2):

You'd usually use reduce to sum the values in an array of objects (what your data will be - assumption as you don't show data). Just call the following addCredits() function with your array, replace `b.credit` with the property that holds the number to sum:

```js
var creditHours = [{
  creditHours: 1
}, {
  creditHours: 2
}];

function addCredits(data) {
  return data.reduce(function(a, b) {
    a += b.creditHours;
    return a;
  }, 0)
}
console.log(addCredits(creditHours));
```

Comment: I notice that the ` console.log("credit hours: " + creditHours);` from the first function is not working for the new function to add together.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @thesayhey

Comment: I want to replace `b.credit` with ` var creditHours = ddObjectArray[eeIndex].creditHours;` but the console is complaining `creditHours is not defined`

Comment: There's no point of doing this. Replace b.credit with b.creditHours ... @thesayhey

Comment: shouldn't the console.log spit out creditHours as well ? and the json object be creditHours too?

Comment: You can name your variable however you like @thesayhey

Comment: I think I know why this isn't adding the credit hours up. 1. it needs to ignore NULL values and 2. there is an AJAX function that calls the data and this is where I should be grabbing the credit hours.

Comment: You'll need to add the data, otherwise I can't help @thesayhey

Comment: added the ajax stuff i was telling you about :)

Comment: Again. Add sample data @thesayhey

Comment: added data above. Look at ```        function listUpdate(rangeValue) {
           console.log('range value' + rangeValue);
 // DATA:  range value6```

Comment: I think the function needs to live in the ajax call and not as a function but a for loop.

Comment: I think what I probably needed to look for was a way to add data through the HTML/JS ? It's a bit confusing to me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185132/selecting-and-adding-functions-to-divs-via-for-loop

Comment: No, what you need to do is to post the data I've been asking for several times. Please stop to write message here as long as your question doesn't have those @thesayhey

Comment: You are kidding me, right? @thesayhey I will stop to answer from now on.

Comment: baao i don't understand what data you are referring to... this is what i am getting :(